# php desktop chrome .exe does play mp4 files

Tags: php, phpdesktop

I have created .exe file in Php desktop chrome. I am trying to play mp4 files but the mp4 file is not playing. What should I do? I am using PHP version 7.2
Here is my code

```
<resource identifier="__5WtkOHCMKhl_course_id_RES" type="webcontent" href="index_lms.html" adlcp:scormtype="sco">
```

Comment: Your code is missing.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Desktop is an open source project and does not include proprietary codecs support. You can however build PHP Desktop from sources along with CEF with MP4 / H264 / AC3 / EAC3 codecs support, but it's a long process.